# How to transpose numpy ndarray in place?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy.

I have an ndarray with shape of [T, H, W, C] and I want to transpose it to become like: [T, C, H, W]. However, this array is huge and I want to be memory-efficient.

But I just found `np.transpose` to do this which is **not in-place**.

Why do operations like `np.transpose` don't have their in-place counterpart?

I used to think that any operation named `np.Bar` would have its in-place counterpart named `np.Bar_`, only to find that this is not the truth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) docs

> A view is returned whenever possible.

meaning no extra memory is allocated for the output array.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> B = np.transpose(A, axes=(0, 3, 1, 2))

>>> A.shape
(2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> B.shape
(2, 5, 3, 4)
```

You can use [`np.shares_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html) to check if `B` is a view of `A`:

```
>>> np.shares_memory(A, B)
True
```

So, you can safely transpose your data with`np.transpose`.

Comment: The idea was to demonstrate that the kind of transpose OP intends to perform does return a view rather than a copy.

Comment: so what happens if I do ``A = np.transpose(A,axes=xxx)``? Does it need memory re-allocation?

Comment: @游凯超, If `np.transpose(A,axes=xxx)` is a view then `A` is just reassigned (both point to the same data structure).

Comment: is there any solution if we want the real transpose rather than a view?

Comment: @JingpengWu, a quick-and-dirty approach would be to copy the array and then transpose the copy.

Comment: @taras that is not really in-place though. The whole point of in-place is reduce memory usage. For the copy implementation, we can just do normal transpose, and then make it continuous in numpy.

this is the wiki explaining to algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: @JingpengWu https://github.com/seung-lab/fastremap This might suit your purposes as of version 1.2.0. ^_^ It can transpose in-place for 2d, 3d, and 4d arrays.

Comment: Check that, as of version 1.2.1.